# Particles menu is blank

Tags: interface, particles

When i select the plate (see picture) the option for particles remains blank. Any ideas? noob with only 10 hours in blender.

[image]

Comment: use the slider on the right side of the screen to slide up to where your particles are. https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eHEo.gif

Comment: Thank you, note to self stop when its midnight or you make stupid mistakes

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that the slider in the particles tab is all the way down. Would scrolling up solve your issue?